# Suppressing overly-strict error messages in Angular2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add an arbitrary custom attribute to an `a` tag in Angular2 and it's being a PITA, throwing an error message.  Did I inadvertently turn on 'angry mommy mode' somehow?  How can I add a custom attribute and not have the framework flip out?

```
<a [routerLink]=" ['some', 'location'] " data-custom="val" >Link</a>

EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'custom' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like `[attr.data-custom]="val"` and angular will parse it correctly

Comment: It only worked once I removed the brackets: `attr.data-custom="val"`, but that did the trick